# Let a program run x seconds but preserve the ability to control-C

Tags: fork, sh

I'm looking for a way to run a script for `x` seconds with still the possibility to interrupt it before those `x` seconds are past.

If I didn't need the ability to Ctrl-C I'd write

```
./my_script &
sleep $x
kill $!
```

But here if I Ctrl-C during the script the fork keeps running.

I kinda know how to kill the script if launched in a sub-shell:

```
trap "echo sub-script terminated" INT
(./my_script)
trap - INT
```

but I do not know how to transpose that to a fork (I do not get clearly the differences between the two concepts I have to admit).

**EDIT**: I'd like to know how portable are the solutions btw, if you can mention that in your answers, that'd be of great value to me.

Comment: @the_person_who_voted_the_question_as_off-topic: `°_o`

Comment: Maybe you can use ENV Variable as flag. So during the script you look for that flag and if it's true you exit. Of course you toggle the flag when you catch the Ctrl-C signal.

Comment: I feel like there must be a cleaner solution to this problem though :(

Comment: I don't have other ideas. Maybe you should ask on superuser ! http://superuser.com/ seems more appropriate :)

Comment: well it's a question about programming in bash so I don't see why superuser would be more appropriate than so

Comment: Don't know, but on superuser, it's not coder, it's admin, so they should masterise in bash :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
timeout $x ./my_script
```

If you have a reasonably new GNU Coreutils, [`timeout`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html) is included there.  Before, there used to be a number of slightly incompatible `timeout` variants from different sources (the one I have in most places comes from the Postfix distribution originally IIRC).

If you don't have `timeout` for your distro, there are many shell and Perl hacks out there.